# Is there a way in Trello to link cards?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is there a way to maintain an inventory together with a shopping list, for instance?

That is, when the inventory gets below a certain threshold, an item should be added to the shopping list, and when it's bought it should go to the inventory, etc.

Comment: This would be great for managing a project with trello, if the team are open to adding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this currently though it might be possible through the [API](https://trello.com/board/trello-public-api/4ed7e27fe6abb2517a21383d).

Comment: That's fast (the answer)